# How to make intent go back to previous fragment?

Tags: android

I have a fragment which opens an activity (let's call it `activity1`). This activity (`activity1`) can open another activity (let's call it `activity2`). And again this activity (`activity2`) can open another activity (let's call it `activity3`). I would like to get the following behavior:

- When pressing back in `activity1` it will go back to the fragment - works.
- When pressing back in `activity2` it will go to `activity1` - works.
- When pressing back in `activity3` it will go back to the fragment - does not work.

The last one does not work because it goes back to `activity1`. When moving from `activity2` to `activity3` I finish `activity2`. But how can I also finish  `activity1`? I can't use the `(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)` flag like it was suggested in previous topics because I want it to go back to already opened fragment. How can I remove `activity1` from the intent stack?

Answer (score 0):

if you want the flexibility to have activity3 to show any activity when it finishes, you need to override onKeyDown and handle KEYCODE_BACK.
in Activity3.java

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                //show fragment or startActivity to show activity with fragment
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```